# Cannot access database through linked server

Tags: c#, exception, ado.net, linked-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am using the SqlBulkCopy Feature to store bulk data in to Sql database.

For Ex: bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "employeetable". This code works fine. But In a scenario, where i don't have access to the Destination database directly through Connection string. A linked server is only provided to the destination database. When i am trying to connect the Destination database through the Linked server(Code Below)

For Ex:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destcon, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, sqltran))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "LinkedSeverName.database.dbo." + employeetable;  
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

I get the following error,

> Cannot access destination table 'LinkedSeverName.database.dbo.employeetable'. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'XXX'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly

Is there any other way to overcome this error and achieve the task. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can look into is, four part name is case sensitive. Make sure that you are specifying correct case.